# webstart-maven-plugin custom jnlp template variable list

Tags: java, maven, maven-webstart-plugin

So I'm trying to create a custom JNLP template for the maven webstart plugin. From the examples I've seen on http://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/examples/inbuilt_templates.html, they use various variables. I was trying to find out, what variables exist (is there a list somewhere)? And where are they defined? Can I set them/change them somewhere?